# Is this a correct way to pass a function into a struct?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I looked but couldn't find a direct reference for this question. I'm new to function pointers (and C), so I don't know all the tricks one can do yet :)

I've effectively got a function:

```
void select_comparator(My_Struct *structure, int (*comp)(int x, int y)) {
    ...
```

...where `My_Struct` has prototype:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int (*comp)(int x, int y);
} My_Struct;
```

Modulo some minor details. I just want to know if the following is correct syntax:

```
void select_comparator(My_Struct *structure, int (*comp)(int x, int y)) {
    structure->comp = comp;
}
```

It seems almost too easy, and I'm worried it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's wrong: this is the basis of callbacks in [c](/questions/tagged/c). Just make sure the signature of your function pointer matches the type defined in your structure. Where it gets remotely tricky is when you're using this in a large project, and people forget to check if the function pointer is valid or `void`, along with arguments, etc.

## Code Listing

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor directives.
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>


/*******************************************************************************
 * Data types.
 ******************************************************************************/
typedef struct my_struct {
    int (*comp)(int x, int y);
} My_Struct;


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes.
 ******************************************************************************/
int c(int a, int b);
void select_comparator(My_Struct *structure, int (*comp)(int x, int y));


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function definitions.
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void)
{
    My_Struct s;

    select_comparator(&s, &c);
    s.comp(1, 2);

    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void select_comparator(My_Struct *structure, int (*comp)(int x, int y))
{
    structure->comp = comp;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int c(int a, int b)
{
    int ret = 0;
    if (a < b) {
        ret = (-1);
    } else if (a > b) {
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about return types! That actually *is* going to be pertinent, because I am working on a large project....

Answer (score 1):

The code is ok.

Though note that function pointers have plain horrible syntax in C, particularly when passed to/returned from functions. Try writing something like "function returning function-pointer and taking function-pointer as parameter" and you'll soon realize that the syntax is pure madness.

It is therefore a good idea to make function pointers "fall in line" with the rest of the language by using typedefs.

You code could be written like this:

```
typedef int comp_t (int x, int y); // typedef a function type

typedef struct {
    comp_t* comp;   // pointer to such a function type
} My_Struct;

void select_comparator(My_Struct *structure, comp_t* comp) {
    structure->comp = comp;
}
```

Now the code turns easier to read and the function pointer behaves pretty much like any other pointer.

Comment: They can be daunting, but there's not **that** bad. I was lucky to come across [a really good explanation of the "right-left rule"](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) early on in my `C` studies, and it made a lot of the quirks of the language easier to follow.

Comment: @DevNull No, they really **are** horrible. I have around 20 years of C experience and still it is no trivial task even for me to write something like `function taking parameters... returning function-pointer-to-function taking parameters...` (plus qualifiers on top of that). Writing something like that without typedef will take me 10 minutes. Writing it with typedefs will take me 10 seconds. The syntax **is** that retarded, period. It is not even worth anyone's time to bother learning the syntax - it is useless knowledge. Just learn typedef, go be productive, write pretty and readable code.

Comment: I've been in the industry about the same length of time, and had a very different experience. The logic to interpret them, while messy, is rigid and well defined. True, typedefs have their place, and make it a lot easier to work with function pointers with larger teams.